# Looking for a Norton Commander -like file manager to connect via SSH to a linux server from Windows

Tags: windows, linux, ssh, file-management

I am looking for a tool to manage files on a remote linux computer via a SSH session from my windows 7 computer. I want this tool to help me copy files from one folder on that computer to another folder again on the same computer. Also I want selecting feature so that I can select the files one by one or totally and do some file manipulation on them.

Please tell me your suggestions.

Comment: In 2024, for Windows 10 and up, Brows can connect via SSH. https://brows.app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinSCP http://winscp.net/eng/index.php

Comment: WinSCP does not let me set both tabs to remote computer. Because of that for example you can not copy files from a folder to another folder, both in destination computer.

Comment: @Farshid: Yes you can. You just have to drag it into the directory tree or type in the destination folder. Otherwise, you can run two instances of WinSCP in explorer mode and just drag from one window to the other.

Comment: Oops, did not think about how easy to deal with your prob because most of time I just copy from local to remote only. Nice solution @Farshid